# Using function to print asteriks

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int asteriks (int sides,int row=1,int col=1)
{
    for(row;row<=sides;row++)
    {
        for(col;col<=sides;col++)
            cout<<"*";
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return asteriks;
}

int main()
{
    int side;

    cout<<"Enter a number to print out square asteriks. Ex: If a number is 5, it will  print 5x5 total of 25 asteriks in square. :"<<endl;
    cin>>side;

    cout<<asteriks(side);

    // ...
```

This is one the assignment that I have to do for my C++ class. I get an error at "return asteriks" it says that return value type doesn't match the function type.

The goal in this program is to print square asteriks by user entering a side (e.g 5, it will print 5x5) using function.

Comment: That's because the value you're returning doesn't match the function's type. Check out the function's type, and what it is you're returning.

Comment: Your return statement uses the function name, not a variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets check your code:

```
cout<<asteriks(side); // this implies that asteriks function is returning a value

int asteriks (int sides,int row=1,int col=1) // this implies this function return an integer

return asteriks; // this implies that asteriks is the integer you return from the function, but asteriks is not a variable
```

So you either have to change the function type to String and return a String istead of doing the `cout` inside the function, or you want the `asteriks` function to be of type void, with no return and call it like this: `asteriks(side);`

Answer (score 1):

delete

```
return asteriks;
```

change the function return value to void and change

```
void asteriks (int sides,int row=1,int col=1)
```

and change

```
cout<<asteriks(side);
```

for

```
asteriks(side);
```

you're calling a function to print the square, It doesn't have sense to return something.

the problem with your code is, you are trying to return asteriks, and asteriks isn't a "integer type".

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. When I tried your suggestion, it only prints out "*****" after entering 5 as number.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that in a shorter way like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int asterisks;
    cout<<"Enter a number to print out square asteriks. Ex: If a number is 5, it will  print 5x5 total of 25 asteriks in square. :"<<endl;
    cin >> asterisks;
    for(int i = 0; i < asterisks; i++) cout << string(asterisks, '*') << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Even shorter: `main(i,a){for(a=10;i<a*a+a;)putchar(i++%(a+1)?42:10);}`. Wops, wrong site.